# Is it possible to create a proportional triple Venn Diagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram, eulerr

I am trying to create a proportional Venn Diagram with three groups. I searched the web and tried with 3 different packages: `Venndiagram`, `venneuler` and `eulerr`. However, with none it seems that it creates a correct proportional diagram. Can anyone help how to do this?

I tried with `Venndiagram` package:

```
library(Venndiagram)
draw.triple.venn(58, 44, 37, 44, 27, 37, 27, c("A", "B", "C"), euler.d = TRUE, scaled = TRUE)
```

Although `scaled = TRUE`, this gave me the following diagram:
[image]

When using `venneuler` package:

```
library(venneuler)
v <- venneuler(c(A = 4, B = 0, C = 0, "A&B" = 10, "A&C" = 17, "B&C" = 0, "A&B&C" = 27))
plot(v)
```

[image]

This seemed to work better. However, as you can see, there is an area of B and C outside of A although this needs to be 0. Maybe this is impossible with circles?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is impossible with circles. However, if you're willing to use ellipses instead, the latest development version of **eulerr** (that I happen to the be creator of) can help you.

```
devtools::install_github("jolars/eulerr")

v <- eulerr::euler(c(A = 4, B = 0, C = 0,
                     "A&B" = 10, "A&C" = 17, "B&C" = 0, "A&B&C" = 27),
                   shape = "ellipse")
plot(v)
```

yields

[image]

Which is a perfect fit.

```
      original fitted residuals regionError
A            4      4         0           0
B            0      0         0           0
C            0      0         0           0
A&B         10     10         0           0
A&C         17     17         0           0
B&C          0      0         0           0
A&B&C       27     27         0           0

diagError: 0 
stress:    0
```

Comment: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [eulerr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘eulerr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/eulerr’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/eulerr’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: Thanks, this option seems perfect! However, when I run the command  >devtools::install_github("jolars/eulerr")
an error occures. 

I have posted it above (didn't fit in one comment, sorry)
Do you know what happens here? Do I need to install additional packages?

Comment: I know next to nothing about OSX, but are you maybe missing clang?

Comment: Rectangles will also work :-)